# How can i Implement admob mediation with facebook audience network in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, admob, facebook-audience-network

This is what i get in the console
[message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gamoy.png)
I have implemented sdk as well as adapter

When I hot restart app after build the app crashes automatically
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNxSD.png)